# Performance of inserting form data into many to many relationship using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, insert, many-to-many, insert-update

I am learning ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework. I tried to create a gallery with photo and photo tags. I achieved what I planned somehow, but as I'm still learning, I don't know if what I coded is the best way or not, so changes or corrections would be welcome.

photo table:

```
        photoID
        ownerID
        Path
        imagename
```

tag table:

```
        tagID
        tagName
```

phototag table:

```
        phototagID
        tagID
        photoID
```

This is the sample code inside my controller action which is handling photo upload:

```
        HttpPostedFileBase myFile = Request.Files["UploadImage"];

        //tags are comma seperated string posted using ajax
        string tagtext = Request.Form["tags"];

        // converting tags to string arrays to iterate while storing
        string[] tags = tagtext.Split(',');
        string OrgImgName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(myFile.FileName);
        myFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(FilePath, myFile.FileName));             

        //session userid
        var UserID = (int)Session["UserID"];

        // Saving photo to db
        photo p = new photo();
        p.ownerID = UserID;
        p.photopath = filepath;
        p.photoname = myFile.Filename;
        db.photo.add(p);
        db.savechanges();                       

        // iterating through tags to insert into database
        for (int i = 0; i < tags.Length; i++)
            {
                var tagname = tags[i].ToString();
                // checking for tag name if exists
                if (!db.tags.Any(n =>n.TagName == tagname))
                    {
                        tag t = new tag();
                        t.TagName = tags[i].ToString();
                        db.tags.Add(t);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }

            }

        // getting photoid of last inserted photo of user
        var photoid = (from ph in db.photos where ph.ownerID == UserID orderby ph.photoID descending select ph.photoID).FirstOrDefault();

        //iterating through tags to update many to many common table
        for (int i = 0; i < tags.Length; i++)
            {
                var tagname = tags[i].ToString();
                phototag ph = new phototag();
                ph.PhotoId = photoid;
                ph.TagId = (from t in db.tags where t.TagName == tagname select t.TagId).FirstOrDefault();
                db.phototags.Add(ph);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

The above code is giving the output that I expected. Now I tested only for single user posting one photo at a time; if there is a situation where single user uploads multiple photos at a time I 
think it becomes nested for loops which is not good performance-wise, and if many users upload photos at a time I don't know what the effect will be on the code and server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you understand better how works the many-to-many relationship in EF, I'm going to proporse you the following model:

```
public class Photo
{
    public Photo()
    {
        Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }

    public int PhotoId { get; set; }

    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }   
}

public class Tag
{
    public Tag()
    {
        Photos = new HashSet<Photo>();
    }

    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public string TagName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

With this model you don't need to have a PhotoTag class, because EF will create it for you. EF build a join table in the database with the appropriate keys of the tables it’s joining. The keys are both primary keys of the join table and foreign keys pointing to the joined tables Also, you can configure that relationship as I show below:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    //...

    public IDbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Photo>().HasMany(p => p.Tags).WithMany(c => c.Photos).Map(c=>c.ToTable("PhotoTag"));

    } 
}
```

Now, with this configuration, you only need to create first the Photo and then add the tags asociated with it:

```
 using (var db = new YourContext())
 {
    //Create the photo
     var photo = new Photo() { OwnerId = 1, ImageName = "Picture", Path = @"E:\Pictures" };

     //Add the tags
     photo.Tags.Add(new Tag() { TagName = "Family" });
     photo.Tags.Add(new Tag() { TagName = "Friend" });

     db.Photos.Add(photo);
     db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

You don't need to worry about fill the data in the PhotoTag table, EF will do it for you.

### Update

To find if exist a tag or not, you can do this:

```
var tag=db.Tags.Contains(tagid);//if you have the tagid
```

Or also, doing this:

```
var tag=db.Tags.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Name==tagName);//if you have the tagName
```

Now, with that tag reference, you could do something like this:

```
if(tag!=null)
{
  photo.Tags.Add(new Tag() { TagName = tagName });
}
else
{
  if(photo.Tags.All(t=>t.Id!=tag.Id))
     photo.Tags.Add(tag);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer  and sorry for the late reply..how to check for if tag already exists in tags table... if it exists i just want to link to the same, if not then add it to table...